# Are there Virtual Twain Scanners? Sort like Daemon Tools virtual CD

Tags: image-scanner

I am testing a scanning application and currently I dont have any scanner to plug it in. Is there anyway to have a virtual scanner like Daemon Tools does with Virtual CD Drives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a [Sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/) with a sample TWAIN implementation, including a virtual scanner.  I haven't found anything similar for WIA.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Although it would have been better if there were more options but since it is free I got no complaints and for on the fly testing it works. Awesome.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552711.aspx seems to be ~similar for WIA

Comment: @ThorDivDev: Did you ever succeed with this SourceForge project? I have downloaded it yesterday and despite my best efforts, I haven't been able to do even the most basic scan operation. I continue getting exceptions setting one property or the other, mostly when trying to set Area or Units. Not setting these properties avoids exceptions, but then the scan operation goes into sleep (sleep of the dead that is).

Comment: I used it with Windows XP two-three years ago on a laptop. I didn't adjust any values as all I needed was just the stock image. I am sorry I can't give you more help.

Comment: The virtual scanner didn't work for me on Windows 8. The one from TerminalWorks posted by Harold worked great. It has a 15 day trial.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a pretty simple to use application called UniTwain. I am using it and it works really nice for my users. You can download it from http://www.terminalworks.com/unitwain

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make people aware of GenDS

<kbd>[**Download ZIP**](https://web.archive.org/web/20081210202031/http://www.dosadi.com/pub/beta/GenDS.zip)</kbd>

According to [this](http://www.eztwain.com/gends.htm) web page, GenDS

> is a ready-to-build Microsoft C++ 6.0 project that compiles to a
>   generic TWAIN Datasource (DS)

I am in the process of compiling it so I cannot give further advise.