# Simulate or Virtual Twain source for Twain development

Tags: testing, virtual, twain, emulation

For developing a web based scan solution, I would love to test it on Windows or Mac without actually hooking up a scanner to my box. So is there a program/tool that emulates or gives me a virtual twain source with some default image data?

Comment: Duplicate of [Are there Virtual Twain Scanners? Sort like Daemon Tools virtual CD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060420/are-there-virtual-twain-scanners-sort-like-daemon-tools-virtual-cd)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Twain sample driver that comes along with the twain sample application up on source forge should have what you're looking for.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/TWAIN%202%20Sample%20Application/

Comment: It also has adf support, so this was really the great addition for testing, unluckily this is Windows only for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are plenty of solutions for this. We are using TerminalWorks' UniTwain application. The users are very satisfied as it is pretty simple to use and it does it's job. This is the download link: http://www.terminalworks.com/unitwain

Answer (score 2):

both of above are paid apps.
there is one open source:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/

you need Data Source, it adds virtual scanner, which gives you the file if asked.
dont know if the received sample file can be changed, but for testing its good.